# Text Will not show for selected Item in ComboBox

Tags: wpf, windows, wpf-controls

I feel really stupid for asking this but I have been thrashing for over 8 hours. How do I get the Selected Item to show its text in my WPF combo box when selected?

[image: Diplay Options]

Above is an option dialog that allows users to select and configure the available tournament displays. The problem is the selected combo box item shows the UserControl instead of the Display name.

**On Window Loaded**:

```
        //_displayer is a private member populated using MEF
        //[ImportMany(typeof (IDisplayer))] 
        //private IEnumerable<IDisplayer> _displayers;
        DisplayTypeComboBox.ItemsSource = _displayers;
```

**The ComboBox Xaml:**

```
   <ComboBox
     Name="DisplayTypeComboBox"
     Grid.Column="1"
     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
     Grid.Row="1" 
     IsEditable="False"
     SelectionChanged="DisplayTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding DisplayerName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
   </ComboBox>
```

**The IDisplayer:**

```
public interface IDisplayer
{
    string DisplayDataLocation { get; set; }
    string DisplayerName { get; }
    string DisplayerDescription { get;}
    bool WatcherEnabled { get; }
    UserControl View { get; }
    string DisplayerImageLeft { get; set; }
    string DisplayerImageRight { get; set; }
    void Update();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't even want to think about how many hours I have spent trying to solve what should be a simple problem. Why is it so hard to get your selected text to appear as the selected value? I give up, WPF you have beat me into submission. I changed the control to a list box it takes up more room to display the selectable Items but at least it works.

```
   <ListBox
     Name="DisplayTypeComboBox"
     Grid.Column="1"
     Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
     Grid.Row="1" 
     SelectionChanged="DisplayType_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Label Content="{Binding DisplayerName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same thing. Took me a while too. :(
You should have used the ItemContainerStyle and not ItemTemplate.
Because ComboBox wraps the internal items with a ComboBoxItem - you basically wrapped the ComboBoxItem with another one.

Comment: Hmmm I must be missing somthing I cant seem to do anything as far as templating the bound data with ItemContainerStyle

Answer (score 0):

Try using a TextBlock to bind to the DisplayerName instead of a ComboboxItem.  I believe that when you set the itemsource, the combo control will wrap the items inside comboboxitems controls automatically.

Edit:  I misunderstood your question.  Try setting the SelectionBoxItemTemplate.

Comment: Well so far I have tried ComboBoxItem, TextBlock, and Label. They all produce the same Result.

Comment: Can you link and e.g. I cant seem to set it the seam way I did the ItemTemplate. All my googling is not turning up anything simple and clean.

Comment: The SelectionBoxItemTemplate property is the property you need to set.. unfortunately, it's private.  Try creating your own ComboBox style and setting that SelectionBoxItemTemplate to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Check what DisplayerName member actually contains. Most likely it contains the UserControl name instead of the Display name.

Comment: The DipslayerName field does have the valid string.
The Items in the drop down contain the correct DisplayerName string i.e "Qualifying Scrolling Standings", Once its selected I cant figure out how to tell the control to use DisplayerName field as the selected display value.

Comment: What does your code for DisplayTypeComboBox_SelectionChanged method look like? Do you somehow mess with the SelectedItem after the user changed it?

Comment: It is just setting the long description.
SelectedDisplayer = (IDisplayer)DisplayTypeComboBox.SelectedItem;  
if (SelectedDisplayer != null)  
LongDiscriptionLabel.Text = SelectedDisplayer.DisplayerDescription;